# POSTされたフォームの日本語がはてなマークに文字化けしてしまう

Tags: jsp, servlet

jspのsubmit時、postだとformの日本語がはてなマークに文字化けしてしまいます。
また、getだとform情報が文字化けは起きません。
JSPに設定している項目↓

```html
・<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=Windows-31J" %>
・<html lang="ja">
・<form method="GET" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

他に設定しなければいけない項目があるのかなと思い調査中なのですが、解決しておりません。
解決方法の分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

受け取ったdoPostメソッド内で、form情報を取得する前に

```html
setCharacterEncoding(utf-8)
```

を設定すると、正しくエンコードされます。

また、Windows-31Jでpostしたい場合には、既にpageエンコード設定でWindows-31Jが指定されているので、formタグでaccept-charsetにWindows-31Jを指定する必要はありません。

Answer (score 1):

Formを使う頁数が多い場合や複数人でページを作るときは、Tomcatや下記のサイトのような設定で一律に扱うCharsetを固定すると楽になります。
http://s2container.seasar.org/2.4/ja/garble.html

Answer (score 0):

ご質問からはTomcatをご利用かわかりませんでしが
この辺とかいかがでしょうか？
http://www.javaroad.jp/servletjsp/sj_servlet13.htm